# According to Calvinist, are there another kind group of people besides "they" in Revelation 22:4-5?

Tags: eschatology, heaven, revelation, kingdom-of-god, kingdom-of-heaven

> Revelation 22:
>   (2) and flowing down the middle of the city's
>   street. On each side of the river was the tree of life, which bears
>   fruit twelve times a year, once each month; and its leaves are for the
>   healing of **the nations**.
>
> (3) Nothing that is under God's curse will be found in the city. The
>   throne of God and of the Lamb will be in the city, and **his
>   servants** will worship him.
>
> (4) **They** will see his face, and his name will be written on
>   **their** foreheads.
>
> (5) There shall be no more night, and **they** will not need lamps or
>   sunlight, because the Lord God will be their light, and **they** will
>   rule as kings forever and ever

As long as I understand (from reading the internet), it seems Revelation 22 is about a place (called heaven or kingdom of God) AFTER the Judgment Day. No more mortal human.

Assuming that my understanding is correct, so the inhabitants of the heaven are all :
1. His servants (verse 3)
2. have His name on their foreheads and see His face (verse 4)
3. rule as kings forever and ever (verse 5)

My questions are :
- are the inhabitants of heaven = the nations mentioned in verse 2 ?
- who are to be ruled and why ? are the inhabitants rule to each other ?

I realize that my questions are not valid if my understanding is not correct.

Comment: @NigelJ, I've edited the question. Now it's asking to a particular perspective. Thank you for your suggestion.